# Consolibyte | example_mysql_mirror.php | syncing not working on PHP Version 5.6 | Response is not well-formed XML

Tags: php, quickbooks

Sync script is working perfectly on my local machine (PHP 5.6.31). i have deployed code on live server (PHP Version 5.6.34), disabled all errors using this code "ini_set('display_errors', 0);" but now i am getting "QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed
Error message: Client found response content type of 'text/xml', but expected 'text/xml'." error.

Comment: Can you log the HTTP requests and see what the actual HTTP headers your web server is sending are? Or, if there's nothing sensitive here can you post or PM me the Web Connector password so I can run a test script?

Comment: Also, post your code. Not as a link - post it. And remove any sensitive information from your log file too.

Comment: @keith, thanks for reply. i have found the reason of this issue.

This error occurred due to "TimeCreated" and "TimeModified" column values in query: "Incorrect datetime value: '2018-01-19T23:04:21+05:00' for column 'TimeCreated' 

The reason was that on live environment, mysql "Strict" mode was enabled however on my local machine mysql "Strict" mode was disabled. In strict mode, dateformat like "2018-01-19T23:04:21+05:00" is invalid. I disabled "stict" mysql mode on live and it worked.